# Rails 6 Add input to listing in page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I need your help to find out how can I achieve showing what the user inputs in a form in a table below the form. There is a model (Inputs) and I want the  to show just the recent additions to the database's table... I already have the form and the table shows the  model's index which contains too many rows, I hope I can make myself clear. I know there will be some jQuery and Ajax involved. The new input records will be added to the database's table, but I want to show just what the user inputs. Maybe there's already a Railscast for this or some other solution, I just don't know how to search or ask. Thank you.
Here's the form I already have:

```
<%= form_with(model: input, id: "new-input", local: false) do |form| %>
  <% if input.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(input.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this input from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% input.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
   
  <div style="padding-top: 50px;padding-bottom: 30px;">
    <table class="show-table">
      <tr>
        <td>Proveedor:</td>
        <td colspan="3"><%= form.collection_select :supplier_id, @suppliers, :id, :name, { :prompt => "Proveedor sugerido"}%></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Factura:</td>
        <td><%= form.text_field :invoice %></td>
        <td>Fecha:</td>
        <td><%= form.date_field :input_date %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="void-space">
      <br>
    </div>
    <table class="index-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Producto</td>
          <td>Precio Unit.</td>
          <td>Cantidad</td>
          <td>Costo</td>
          <td>Ubicación</td>
          <td>Acción</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <%  %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= form.collection_select :product_id, @products, :id, :name, { :prompt => "Producto"}%></td>
          <td><%= form.text_field :price %></td>
          <td><%= form.text_field :quantity %></td>
          <td>costo</td>
          <td><%= form.text_field :location %></td>
          <% form.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
          <td><%= form.submit "Guardar", class: "btn success" %></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

This for is rendered from the index.html.erb and it works fine but I don't want to see all the input's table records, just the new ones

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you store the `user_id` on the Product model. In that case you could add a scope on the Product model

```
scope :created_by, ->(user_id) { where(user_id: user_id) }
```

And change your table to use a scoped collection, so it ends up something like

```
<td><%= form.collection_select :product_id, @products.created_by(current_user.id), :id, :name, { :prompt => "Producto"}%></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution, it may be of interest for someone, so here it is: It involves a new action in the controller to handle this situation where I want to show the table listing the records being entered ... Create a route and a new action in *inputs_controller.rb* :

```
# GET /list_inputs
  def list_inputs
    @input_list = params[:input] || []
    new_input
  end
```

'new_input' is a method to iniialize all the instance variables also used in actions 'new' and 'create':

```
def new_input
  if action_name == 'create'
    @input = Input.new(input_params)
  else
    @input = Input.new
  end
  @suppliers = Supplier.all
  @products = Product.all
  @user = current_user
end
```

A view is defined then app/views/inputs/list_inputs.html.erb

```
<h1>Registro de entradas al almacén</h1>

<%= render 'form', input: @input %>

<table class="index-table">
  <tbody id='input-list'>
    <% @input_list.each do |input| %>
      <%= render 'inputs', input: input %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= content_for :footer do %>
  <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<%  end %>
```

A partial for 'inputs' (app/views/inputs/_input.html.erb):

```
<tr>
  <td><%= input.product.name %></td>
  <td><%= input.quantity %></td>
  <td><%= input.user.name %></td>
  <td><%= input.location %></td>
  <td class="botones"><%= link_to 'Destroy', input, class: "btn info", method: :delete, data: { confirm: '¿Confirma?' } %></td>
</tr>
```

And the javaScript to

> respond_to do |format|

in the 'inputs_controller#create' action, which must be located in app/views/inputs/create.js.erb

```
// Render input
var body = document.getElementById("input-list");
body.innerHTML = "<%= j render @input %>" + body.innerHTML;

//Clear and Focus input form
var input = document.getElementById("input_product_id");
input.value = '';
input.focus();
```

This code produces this effect:
[image: input form and table]

I am aware that this may not be the most effective solution but it works, if you are kind enough to comment I'll be thankful.

Comment: Credits to this excellent article: https://joelc.io/ajax-ruby-on-rails-forms